# Error with uploading & downloading binary files using MySQL LONGBLOB

Tags: php, mysql, file, binary, blob

I am using a `LONGBLOG` field in a hosted MySQL database for uploading & downloading attachments. I used the example code found at http://mirificampress.com/permalink/saving_a_file_into_mysql, and have uploaded files into the database (although not able to check each byte in the file).

I got problems when downloading these files: txt files are OK, but binary files such as JPEG or PDF files always have error. The bytes in these binary files have been changed either during uploading or downloading, or during both.

I thought it might be a collation issue, but cannot fix it.

Could anyone give any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example on your linked page is terribly wrong. It uses `addslashes()` as an escaping function for MySQL, and additionally does not properly clean the magic quotes.

Do not use this example.

If you read all the bytes with `file_get_contents()`, all you have to do is use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on it and put it into a string field.

Longblobs do not have an encoding, so this shouldn't be a problem here, but it is always a good idea to set the encoding for your db connection to the right values.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the PHP code for uploading:<br/>
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$fileName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_FILES['file']['name']); $fileType = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_FILES['file']['type']); $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size']; $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])‌​‌​); $sql = "INSERT INTO Attachment SET File_Name = '".$fileName."', File_Type = '".$fileType."', File_Size = '".$fileSize."', File_Content = '".$content."'"; $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);  Will this code work?

Comment: How about the downloading part of the sample code? I tried again but the downloaded file is still interpreted as text encoding instead of binary.

Comment: I cannot read your code in this comment. Please update your question. Do you add the correct "Content-type" header for the images?

Comment: Thanks, I can upload files under your advice and verified them in MySQL Workbench. The binary files uploaded into the server have no error. The only problem is how to retrieve the blob back to the browser.

Comment: Send back as download or as usable image? Your tutorial is less wrong on the first one, but you should really use a correct `Content-type` specifying for example "image/png". You can omit the `Content-disposition` in this case - it is only used to transmit the filename as a suggestion when downloading.

Comment: the problem solved by adding ob_clean() before echoing the file.